# Get back data from the pivot table when store a many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relationship between projects and surveys. I can successfully create a relationship between a survey and a project with

`$userSurvey = $project->surveys()->save($survey);`.

This will create a new record inside the `question_survey` pivot table (The pivot table contains the columns `id`, `question_id` and `survey_id`.)

`$userSurvey` will receive the newly created survey model. Is there any way to receive also the `id` of the new record in the `question_survey` pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When retrieving *many to many* relationships, Laravel will automatically attach the *pivot* to the resulting **Model**, so in your case, `$userSurvey` will automatically have an attribute called `pivot` that holds, well, of course, the pivot.

But by default, that `pivot` attribute only holds the ***foreign keys***, so in your case, the `question_id` and `survey_id`. If you have any other extra attributes,(in your case `id`), simply use the `withPivot` method, as follows.

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'question_survey')
                ->withPivot('id');
}
```

Now you can access the `id` from the pivot table:

```
$userSurvey->pivot->id;
```

---

Bonus, if you think that the `pivot` word just does not fit your wording style, just use the `as` method in your relationship to customize the *variable name* of the **pivot attribute**.

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'question_survey')
                ->as('question_survey')
                ->withPivot('id');
}
```

Now you can access the `id` from the pivot table:

```
$userSurvey->question_survey->id;
```